# Pushwoosh and PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, push-notification, pushwoosh

How do you get a users push token using javascript?   I'm using Pushwoosh, I can get it from the status variable right after the registerDevice is called, but is there away to get it outside of that function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We wrote the token to  file and read it with phonegp.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can do that with this function only. There's going to be another way implemented in the future.